# SVN via Eclipse - Cannot run the code I've checked out

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, junit, svn-checkout

I'm using SVN in Eclipse. I checked out a folder as a project in the workspace. The folder I checked out has a subfolder "trunk", and in the subfolder "trunk" I have my src folder (and other stuff). After checking out I tried to run a file (a JUnit test case): I right clicked on it and selected "run as", expected to find "run as a JUnit test case", but there wasn't such an option. Also, it looks like Eclipse doesn't compile my code: I can edit the code, but don't get any autocompletions or syntax error notifications. What have I done wrong?

Comment: HH, is correct - just want to add:  You'll want to checkout the trunk, not the directory above it.  The .project file will name the local checkout appropriately and this way you won't check out any branches or tags (this could be a lot of data)

Comment: @thekbb: Thanks, I actually checked out the directory above the trunk. Please write this in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, not sure why this took me a while!  Checking out a directory above the trunk is where things got wonky - eclipse couldn't find the project file - and as HH pointed out, didn't know where the source was.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, Eclipse was not able to figure out in this new project: where is the source folder, where are the test source files etc... This is due to a missing or corrupted project file which would normally have metadata about the project (it wasn't committed or you didn't check it out).

For example, in order to get autocompletion and syntax error notifications, Eclipse must recognize your Java files as source files. In the project properties->Java Build Path->Source, make sure your source folder is present.